# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Object'

Tags: angular, typescript

Here, I'm getting an error on `propertiesArray.push(data[id]);` to get a value from JSON file in `Iproperty` interface type of variable.
I'm using VS code for an Angular application. Please let me know where I'm wrong???

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { IProperty } from '../property/IProperty.inteface';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HousingService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getAllProperties():Observable<IProperty[]>{
    return this.http.get('assets/Data/Properties.json').pipe(
      map(data=>{
        const propertiesArray :Array<IProperty>=[];
        for(const id in data)
        {
          if(data.hasOwnProperty(id)){
            propertiesArray.push(data[id]);//Get Error in data[id]
          }
        }
        return propertiesArray;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your loop trying to achieve? Is seems like it’s just Object.values(data).

Comment: change line `this.http.get('assets/Data/Properties.json')` to `this.http.get<any>('assets/Data/Properties.json')`